# Problem using javascript code into my swift application

Tags: swift, swift3, webkit

I'm currently trying to implement a javascript code into my swift application using a `WKWebView`, using that `js` into shortcuts and running it with safari works.

How can this script be implemented to work into my `webview`?

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        //self.navigationItem.hidesBackButton = false
        self.navigationItem.setHidesBackButton(false, animated:true)

        let script =    """
                LONG SCRIPT HERE
                """
        let userScript = WKUserScript(source: script, injectionTime: .atDocumentStart, forMainFrameOnly: true)

        let contentController = WKUserContentController()
        contentController.addUserScript(userScript)

        let webViewConfiguration = WKWebViewConfiguration()
        webViewConfiguration.userContentController = contentController

        let viewContainer = WKWebView(frame: CGRect(x:0, y:0, width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width, height:UIScreen.main.bounds.height), configuration: webViewConfiguration)

        let startURL = URL(string: "MY URL")
        let myURLRequest:URLRequest = URLRequest(url: startURL!)
        viewContainer.load(myURLRequest)

        self.view.addSubview(viewContainer)
        viewContainer.navigationDelegate = self


    }
```

Comment: Add WKNavigationDelegate this delegate and also use WebView.evaluateJavaScript method.

Answer (score 0):

You can use so called `evaluateJavaScript()` in `WkWebView` and then read the result in Swift code.

Here's a quick example:

```
    webView.evaluateJavaScript("document.getElementById('someElement').innerText") { (result, error) in
    if error != nil {
        print(result)
    }
}
```

Comment: yeah but my js is not 1 line only is 200+, so how your code could help me?

Comment: Try wrapping your javascript code in a string and then pass it in evauluateJavascript function.